# AJAX loaded HTML content - Font looks weird

Tags: html, ajax, internet-explorer, fonts

I've got a page which, when a button is clicked, shows a div, loads HTML trough AJAX and then puts the response into the div.

While everything is working fine, I noticed that in Internet Explorer, the font looks weird.
[image: AJAX loaded HTML in IE]

This is only in IE, Chrome for example has no issues displaying it properly
[image: AJAX loaded HTML in Chrome]

What could cause something like this?

**Update**: I've tried it with our terminal server, which also has IE8 installed, and there doesn't seem to be that problem.

Comment: @SiGanteng I'm not a friend of IE, but unfortunately it's the chosen browser of our company.

Comment: do you have clear type font enabled on that PC you are having problem with? http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/step1.aspx

Comment: @SiGanteng Yes, Cleartype is enabled. I tried disabling it, but now, the whole computer font looks strange. Didn't have any effect on the AJAX div though.

Comment: @SiGanteng Both tested IE's were IE 8.

Comment: Hm ok.. have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707032/really-strange-ie8-font-behaviour-that-id-like-to-duplicate

Comment: @SiGanteng I tried enabling ClearType in IE8 (Settings -> Extended -> Multimedia -> Always use CearType for HTML), but didn't change anything.